# Jquery datepicker css problem

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem with the CSS of the datepicker, I downloaded a default template for the UI, but it's different when I use it on my page. I've read that the template uses em so that the size is relative to my page. What can I do to make it the size of what is in the demo without changing the css in the theme that I downloaded?

Comment: I found the solution. I just reordered the calls for the css files. I used the datepicker css first then called my site's css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just reordered the calls for the css files. I used the datepicker css first then called my site's css

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most direct method would be to find the highest level class name that corresponds to the problem and write a new rule like:

```
.ui-datepicker { font-size:0.9em; }
```

And then just keep playing with it until it looks right. That's the brute force method, but without more info, it's the best I can suggest.